# How to update a TableView in QML?

Tags: sql, sqlite, tableview, qml

I am coding a program combining QML and C++. The `TableView` shows a column of a table. I can add or delete the record correctly, but I can not update the `TableView`, which always shows the content before adding or deleting.

How to update the`TableView`?

PS: I do not know whether it is good choice to code with QML and C++ instead of `QWidget` directly.

Comment: can you please add any code snippets or error messages

Comment: Please see the following code.

Answer (score 0):

```
main()
{

    //other code
    ......

    MySqlModel *model = new MySqlModel;//class MySqlModel : public QSqlTableModel
    model->QSqlQueryModel::setQuery("SELECT FieldName1 FROM Table");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty ("SQQL", model);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    //other code
    ......
}
```

In the qml:

```
TableView{

    //other code
    ......

    model: SQQL

    //other code
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

QWidget-based has more default feature built-in, I would suggest you start from there.

1. how to enable edit

   override flags function to enable edit on items, see

   http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/38338-Can-t-edit-my-QTableView-cells

   http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#EditTrigger-enum
2. how to sync changes back to db

   you could manual commit the change per edit, or manually batch all changes in a db transaction, or you could just use sqltablemodel

   http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html#EditStrategy-enum

However, if you need more flexible ui, or it is for a multi-touch device, you should go QML approach

1. make a qabstractview model
2. have qml view that bind to this qabstracttableview model. or using  qt control tool kits

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Now I am using QWidget rather than QML. QML is little difficult for me at the moment.